# How to set initial value to Angular Material mat-select multiple

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

How to set initial value to Angular Material mat-select multiple that uses a list of object for options. The code can be found and runned on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bnxelm?file=app%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts)

Here is the HTML :

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="toppings" multiple>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping.name}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

An here is the typescript :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'select-multiple-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-multiple-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-multiple-example.css'],
})
export class SelectMultipleExample implements OnInit {
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
  formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({ 'toppings': [null, Validators.required] });
  toppingList: any[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Extra cheese' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Mushroom' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Onion' }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup.controls.toppings.setValue([{ id: 1 }]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have to pass whole object.

Replace

```
    this.formGroup.controls.toppings.setValue([{ id: 1 }]);
```

with

```
    this.formGroup.controls.toppings.setValue([this.toppingList[0]]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you try binding the whole object angular will check that objects are selected by comparing their reference. I advise you bind on the object's id since it's unique:
`this.formGroup.controls.toppings.setValue([1]);`
and in html
`<mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping.id">{{topping.name}}</mat-option>`
makes your stackblitz work

Answer (score 0):

> here is working example

[running example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bnxelm-kka7dp?file=app/select-multiple-example.ts)

**.html**

```
 <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="toppings" multiple   (selectionChange)=" showSelectValue($event.value)">
            <mat-option  *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping.name"
      >{{topping.name}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>

    </mat-form-field>
   <p>You selected: {{selected}}</p>
</form>
```

.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

/** @title Select with multiple selection */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-multiple-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-multiple-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-multiple-example.css'],
})
export class SelectMultipleExample implements OnInit {
        selected: any[];

      constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
      formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({ 'toppings': [null, Validators.required] });
      toppingList: any[] = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Extra cheese' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Mushroom' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Onion' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Pepperoni' },
        { id: 5, name: 'Sausage' },
        { id: 6, name: 'Tomato' }
      ];

      ngOnInit() {
        this.formGroup.controls.toppings.setValue(this.selected);
      }

      showSelectValue(mySelect)
      {
        this.selected=mySelect;
        console.log(mySelect);
      }
    }


/**  Copyright 2019 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set initial value in this.formBuilder.group (ex. 2nd and 4th item of list) as below

```
 formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({ 'toppings': [[1, 3], Validators.required] });
```

and in html

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping.id">{{topping.name}}</mat-option> makes your stackblitz work
```