# Select multiple checkbox in dropdown

Tags: angular, checkbox, dropdown

When dropdown is clicked ,after clicking on single checkbox it revert backs to dropdown , i need to select multiple checkbox .

Beginner
concept
```

i tried prevent default method but didn't work

Comment: Add your code here. Your question is not clear

Comment: You can check them out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56932404/how-to-set-initial-value-to-angular-material-mat-select-multiple https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53491710/preselecting-multiple-values-for-mat-select-angular-6

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please give more details in your next post(s). We need to understand your code to give you a good solution.
I don't know if you using `Material` or a custom Select/DropDown control. So here first you can look at [Angular Materials](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#multiple-selection) `mat-select`. It has a property `multiple` and this does exactly what you search for I think.

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Code**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

/** @title Select with multiple selection */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-multiple-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-multiple-example.html',
})
export class SelectMultipleExample {
  toppings = new FormControl('');
  toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
}
```

A Stackblitz example is available, too on their site. Here the result:
[image]

If you don't wanna using *Material* so [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiselect-checkbox-dropdown?file=src/app/multi-select-dropdown/multi-select-dropdown.component.ts) is an example with a custom control:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div (mouseleave)="showDropDown = false">
        <button class="drop-toggle btn flat" (click)="showDropDown=!showDropDown">
            <span *ngIf="checkedList.length<=0">Select</span>
            <span *ngIf="checkedList.length>0">{{checkedList.join(', ')}}</span>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="drop-show" *ngIf="showDropDown">
            <label *ngFor="let a of list">
                <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="a.checked" 
                    (change)="getSelectedValue(a.checked,a.name)" />
                <span>{{a.name}}</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
import {Component,Input,Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-multi-select-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './multi-select-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./multi-select-dropdown.component.css']
})
export class MultiSelectDropdownComponent {
  @Input() list:any[]; 
    
    @Output() shareCheckedList = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() shareIndividualCheckedList = new EventEmitter();
    
    
    checkedList : any[];
    currentSelected : {};

  constructor() {
    this.checkedList = [];
   }

       getSelectedValue(status:Boolean,value:String){
        if(status){
          this.checkedList.push(value);  
        }else{
            var index = this.checkedList.indexOf(value);
            this.checkedList.splice(index,1);
        }
        
        this.currentSelected = {checked : status,name:value};

        //share checked list
        this.shareCheckedlist();
        
        //share individual selected item
        this.shareIndividualStatus();
    }
    shareCheckedlist(){
         this.shareCheckedList.emit(this.checkedList);
    }
    shareIndividualStatus(){
        this.shareIndividualCheckedList.emit(this.currentSelected);
    }
}
```

Result here:
[image]